# Count the frequency of a number in a list but have zeros for numbers that don't occur

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

For example say we have a list of numbers

```
[0, 0, 4, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 9]
```

0 occurs twice, however 1 & 2 do not occur, but then 3 occurs twice, so on and so forth.

Is there a built in function that would give me

```
[2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1]
```

If not how could I go about incorporating zeros for values that do not occur?

Comment: Briefly: `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 `collections.Counter` won't entirely trivially work if you want zeroes in your counts.

Comment: This isn't the same question as the one it's been marked as duplicate of. The OP wants to see zeros too, which `Counter` doesn't to on its own.

Comment: @Mitch - Make a `collections.Counter` and try to retrieve an element that isn't in it: you will get a value of zero.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm well aware, and you could form a simple list comprehension. I'm just saying it's not exactly a duplicate (the zeros in particular seem to be what the OP is hung up on) -  your call I suppose.

Comment: @Mitch - It's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP is only looking for a list that produces equivalent values for each index because they didn't know about `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fair enough, I trust your judgement.

Comment: `>>> import collections
>>> 
>>> clist=[0, 0, 4, 7, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 9]
>>> 
>>> counter = collections.Counter(clist) 
>>> counter
Counter({7: 4, 0: 2, 3: 2, 9: 1, 4: 1})
>>> counter_list=[]
>>> for key,values in counter.items():
...     counter_list.append(values)
... 
>>> counter_list
[2, 1, 2, 1, 4]`